# Integration of azure blobs with apache nifi

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, apache-nifi, azure-blob-storage, apache-nifi-registry

I have tried integrating my azure blobs with Apache nifi and failed. I have used listazureblobStorage and FetchAzureBlobStorage processors.

[image: Processor Property]

Comment: What is the specific error or failed you are facing.
Would suggest you to follow this link : https://blogchinmaya.blogspot.com/2020/12/integrating-apache-nifi-with-azure.html

Answer (score 0):

The other blind you mention have the same Storage Credentials, Storage Account Name, and Storage Account Key. If those values are the same used in the other processors for azure listed above and are shown to work, it could either be an issue with the specific access tokens validity, access to the blob, or something else with the specific NiFi processor.